# How to upload an image to Firebase storage via API (AppGyver)

Tags: firebase, rest, google-cloud-firestore, appgyver

I have a question regarding AppGyver specifically. I am trying to upload an image via a dedicated node, however, no luck as the error's simply saying "Error", therefore I would like to try a more direct approach via the POST method, but couldn't find any dedicated endpoint. Anyone could help me, please?

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

[image: SOlution]

You can try this flow . It works for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hello,
i have the same workflow as you but for some reason it only works if i use the app via web. When I try to do the same thing on my phone, I get an error: "error was thrown because all of the file uploads failed".
Anyone have any idea what the problem might be?
Thank you.